# Проверка наличия аудио потока на сайте с помощью android

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Есть необходимость проверять наличие `Data_Stream` (аудио поток) на сайте для использования в `MediaPlayer`. Как это сделать? (Ловить исключение с помощью `MediaPlayerOnErrorListener` после нескольких неудачных попыток подключения - плохая идея).